# Why does Haskell says this is ambiguous?

Tags: class, haskell, types, ambiguous

I have a type class defined like this :

```
class Repo e ne | ne -> e, e -> ne where
  eTable :: Table (Relation e)
```

And when I try to compile it I get this :

```
* Couldn't match type `Database.Selda.Generic.Rel
                             (GHC.Generics.Rep e0)'
                     with `Database.Selda.Generic.Rel (GHC.Generics.Rep e)'
      Expected type: Table (Relation e)
        Actual type: Table (Relation e0)
      NB: `Database.Selda.Generic.Rel' is a type function, and may not be injective
      The type variable `e0' is ambiguous
    * In the ambiguity check for `eTable'
      To defer the ambiguity check to use sites, enable AllowAmbiguousTypes
      When checking the class method:
        eTable :: forall e ne. Repo e ne => Table (Relation e)
      In the class declaration for `Repo'
   |
41 |   eTable :: Table (Relation e)
   |   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I was expecting everything to be unambiguous since I've explicitly stated that `e` determines `ne` and vice versa.

However, if I try to define my class like this just for the testing purposes, it compiles :

```
data Test a = Test a
class Repo e ne | ne -> e, e -> ne where
    eTable :: Maybe (Test e)
```

I'm not quite sure what is the deal with [`Table`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/selda-0.1.11.2/docs/Database-Selda.html#t:Table) and [`Relation`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/selda-0.1.11.2/docs/Database-Selda-Generic.html#t:Relation) types that causes this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The source of the ambiguity actually has nothing to do with `ne` not being used in the class (which you headed off by using functional dependencies).

The key part of the error message is:

```
  Expected type: Table (Relation e)
    Actual type: Table (Relation e0)
  NB: `Database.Selda.Generic.Rel' is a type function, and may not be injective
```

Note that it's the `e` that it's having trouble matching up, and the NB message drawing your attention to the issue of type functions and injectivity (you really have to know what that all means for the message to be useful, but it has all the terms you need to look up to understand what's going on, so it's quite good as programming error messages go).

The issue it's complaining about is a key difference between type constructors and type families. Type **constructors** are always injective, while type functions in general (and type families in particular) do not have to be.

In standard Haskell with no extensions, the only way you can build compound type expressions was using type *constructors*, such as the left-hand side `Test` in your `data Test a = Test a`. I can apply `Test` (of kind `* -> *`) to a type like `Int` (of kind `*`) to get a type `Test Int` (of kind `*`). Type constructors are [injective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function), which means for any two distinct types `a` and `b`, `Test a` is a distinct type from `Test b`<sup>1</sup>. This means that when type checking you can "run them backwards"; if I've got two types `t1` and `t2` that are each the result of applying `Test`, and I know that `t1` and `t2` are supposed to be equal, then I can "unapply" `Test` to get the argument types and check whether those are equal (or infer what one of them is if it was something I hadn't figured out yet and the other is known, or etc).

Type families (or any other form of type function that isn't known to be injective) don't provide us that guarantee. If I have two types `t1` and `t2` that are supposed to be equal, and they're both the result of applying some `TypeFamily`, there's no way to go from the resulting types to the types that `TypeFamily` was applied to. And in particular, there's no way to conclude from the fact that `TypeFamily a` and `TypeFamily b` are equal that `a` and `b` are equal as well; the type family might just happen to map two distinct types `a` and `b` to the same result (the *definition* of injectivitiy is that it doesn't do that). So if I knew which type `a` was but didn't know `b`, knowing that `TypeFamily a` and `TypeFamily b` are equal doesn't give me any more information about what type `b` should be.

Unfortunately, since standard Haskell only has type constructors, Haskell programmers get well-trained to just presume that the type checker can work backwards through compound types to connect up the components. We often don't even notice that the type checker *needs* to work backwards, we're so used to just looking at type expressions with similar structure and leaping to the obvious conclusions without working through all the steps that the type checker has to go through. But because type checking is based on working out the type of every expression both bottom-up<sup>2</sup> and top-down<sup>3</sup> and confirming that they are consistent, type checking expressions whose types involve type families can easily run into ambiguity problems where it looks "obviously" unambiguous to us humans.

In your `Repo` example, consider how the type checker will deal with a position where you use `eTable`, with `(Int, Bool)` for `e`, say. The top-down view will see that it's used in a context where some `Table (Relation (Int, Bool))` is required. It'll compute what `Relation (Int, Bool)` evaluates to: say it's  `Set Int`, so we need `Table (Set Int)`. The bottom-up pass just says `eTable` can be `Table (Relation e)` for any `e`.

All of our experience with standard Haskell tells us that this is obvious, we just instantiate `e` to `(Int, Bool)`, `Relation (Int, Bool)` evaluates to `Set Int` again and we're done. But that's not actually how it works. Because `Relation` isn't injective there could be some other choice for `e` for which gives us `Set Int` for `Relation e`: perhaps `Int`. But if we choose `e` to be `(Int, Bool)` or `Int` we need to look for two different `Repo` instances, which will have different *implementations* for `eTable`, even though their type is the same.

Even adding a type annotation every time you use `eTable` like `eTable :: Table (Relation (Int, Bool))` doesn't help. The type annotation only adds extra information to the top-down view, which we often already have anyway. The type-checker is still stuck with the problem that there could be (whether or not there actually are) other choices of `e` than `(Int, Bool)` which lead to `eTable` matching that type annotation, so it doesn't know which instance to use. **Any** possible use of `eTable` will have this problem, so it gets reported as an error when you're defining the class. It's basically for the same reason you get problems when you have a class with some members whose types don't use all of the type variables in the class head; you have to consider "variable only used under a type family" as much the same as "variable isn't used at all".

You could address this by adding a `Proxy` argument to `eTable` so that there's something fixing the type variable `e` that the type checker *can* "run backwards". So `eTable :: Proxy e -> Table (Relation e)`.

Alternatively, with the `TypeApplications` extension you now *can* do as the error message suggests and turn on `AllowAmbiguousTypes` to get the class accepted, and then use things like `eTable @(Int, Bool)` to *tell* the compiler which choice for `e` you want. The reason this works where the type annotation `eTable :: Table (Relation (Int, Bool))` doesn't work is the type annotation is extra information added to the context when the type checker is looking top-down, but the type application adds extra information when the type checker is looking bottom-up. Instead of "this expression is required to have a type that unifies with this type" it's "this polymorphic function **is** instantiated at this type".

---

<sup>1</sup> Type constructors are actually even more restricted than just injectivity; applying `Test` to any type `a` results in a type with known structure `Test a`, so the entire universe of Haskell types is straightforwardly mirrored in types of the form `Test t`. A more general injective type function could instead do more "rearranging", such as mapping `Int` to `Bool` so long as it didn't also map `Bool` to `Bool`.

<sup>2</sup> From the type produced by combining the sub-parts of the expression

<sup>3</sup> From the type required of the context in which it is used

Answer (score 4):

`Test` is injective, since it is a type constructor.

`Relation` is not injective, since it is a type family.

Hence the ambiguity.

Silly example:

```
type instance Relation Bool = ()
type instance Relation String = ()

instance Repo Bool Ne where
   eTable :: Table ()
   eTable = someEtable1

instance Repo String Ne where
   eTable :: Table ()
   eTable = someEtable2
```

Now, what is `eTable :: Table ()` ? It could be the one from the first or the second instance. It is ambiguous since `Relation` is not injective.